# Remove multiple whitespaces between columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file (can save as txt, csv, or whatever) that looks like

```
name    num at  res   x   y   z
AB        1 TY   A    1.0-2.3 3.4
BC        2 ER   B    2.1 3.4 -4.5
CD        3 TY   A    2.3 32  -5.6
..
```

I want to be able to just extract all the elements in the 'at' column and then print out a list of the unique elements in that column. The command I used to read in the file was `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`.

However, if I try `print df['at'].head()`, I get an error about hashtables and `KeyError: 'at'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the command you have used to read that CSV file.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`

Comment: You need to post raw data for your csv, otherwise you can post process the column headers if that is the only problem by doing `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

you have problems in line 2024 (pandas counts from 0 !):

> Expected 12 fields in line 2024, saw 13

so you may want to clean up your data or to ignore *bad* lines like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False, ...)
```

**OLD answer:**

most probably, you have read your CSV file incorrectly.

how to check:

```
print df.columns.tolist()
```

and pay attention at the leading/trailing spaces in the column names

how to fix that:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., sep='\s+', ...)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True, ...)
```

Comment: that prints out `['name    num at res         x      y        z']`. There are multiple spaces between each column that didn't show in the Stackoverflow code

Comment: bingo, your DF has only one column!

Comment: so how do I fix it so it has multiple columns?

Comment: both suggestions gives an error `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 2024, saw 13`

Comment: @user5739619, well, then you'll really have to post a sample of your data set if you want us to be able to help you

Comment: I'm not sure what it is for this file. If I try `sep='\t'` I don't get those errors, but `print df.columns.tolist()` still shows it as just one column

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add parameter `sep` as separator to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

- `sep="\s+"` for arbitrary whitespaces
- `sep='\t'` for tab
- `sep=r'\s{2,}'` two or more whitespaces

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""ame num at  res x y z
AB 1 TY A 1.0 -2.3 3.4
BC 2 ER B 2.1 3.4 -4.5
CD 3 TY A 2.3 32 -5.6
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
print df
  ame  num  at res    x     y    z
0  AB    1  TY   A  1.0  -2.3  3.4
1  BC    2  ER   B  2.1   3.4 -4.5
2  CD    3  TY   A  2.3  32.0 -5.6
```

Comment: that gives an error `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 2024, saw 13`

Comment: Can you check what is separator of columns? tab?

Comment: Yes, but maybe whitespaces are in columns - parse error

Comment: I'm not sure what it is for this file. If I try `sep='\t'` I don't get those errors, but `print df.columns.tolist()` still shows it as just one column

Comment: If use `sep='\t'` what is `print df.columns` ?

Comment: But the best is check problematic `2024` row, if there are something wrong - error means `read_csv` read 13 columns instead 12. All line has 12 columns, only in row 2024 is 13 columns.

Comment: If you want remove this problematic row(s), check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#handling-bad-lines).

Comment: I think the best is share your csv (if not confidental) and me or `MaxU` find problem.